# Mule ESB: Message Part was not Recognized. (Does it exist in service WSDL?)

Tags: soap, wsdl, jax-ws, mule

currently I am working with Mule ESB and SOAP JAX-WS. After I configure everything in mule and run it, everything is working fine. However, when I tried to make a request, I got following error:

> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Message part {http://security.fraport.de/zks-eap}uebermittleAusweisdatenRequest was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)

Here is my WSDL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="ZKS-EAP" targetNamespace="http://security.fraport.de/zks-eap" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://security.fraport.de/zks-eap" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/">
<wsdl:documentation>ZKS-EAP 1 - Matrix Version 1.4 - generated by WSDLGen2 2.4.1 on Wed Mar 13 10:59:05 CET 2013</wsdl:documentation>
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://security.fraport.de/zks-eap" xmlns:tns="http://security.fraport.de/zks-eap">
        <xsd:complexType name="kontrolleType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="kontrollZeitpunkt" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
                <xsd:element name="kontrollstelle">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="30"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="lieferantType1">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="lieferantenart" type="tns:lieferantenartEnum"/>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="auftraggeberListe" type="tns:auftraggeberListeType1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="lieferantType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="qS" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                <xsd:element name="lieferantenart" type="tns:lieferantenartEnum"/>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="auftraggeberListe" type="tns:auftraggeberListeType"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="raumzonenType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="raumzone">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="zusatzberechtigungenType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="zusatzberechtigung" type="tns:zusatzberechtigungEnum"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="fahrgenehmigungType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="firmenkuerzel">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="vorfeldnummer">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="amtlichesKennzeichen">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="15"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="fahrzeugtyp">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="fahrzeugmarke">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="fahrgestellnummer">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="auftraggeberListeType1">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="auftraggeber" type="tns:auftraggeberType1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="auftraggeberListeType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="auftraggeber" type="tns:auftraggeberType"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="nameType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="titel">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="vorname">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="nachname">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:simpleType name="lieferantenartEnum">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="Bekannt"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Subunternehmer"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:complexType name="mitarbeiterType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="personalnummer">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="name" type="tns:nameType"/>
                <xsd:element name="bild">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="eUFreistellung" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="funktionsbezeichnung">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="firma">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="ausweisType1">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="nummer">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="16"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="ausweisType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="nummer">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="16"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="gueltigBis" type="xsd:date"/>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="farbe" type="tns:farbeEnum"/>
                <xsd:element name="gueltigkeit" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="bemerkung">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="400"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="mitnahmenachweisType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="personengruppe">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="100"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="gegenstaende" type="tns:gegenstaendeType"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="fahrerlaubnisType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="zugeordneteFirma">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="gueltigSeit" type="xsd:date"/>
                <xsd:element name="klassen" type="tns:klassenType"/>
                <xsd:element name="fahrzeugtypen" type="tns:fahrzeugtypenType"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="berechtigungType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="raumzonen" type="tns:raumzonenType"/>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="mitnahmenachweise" type="tns:mitnahmenachweiseType"/>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="zusatzberechtigungen" type="tns:zusatzberechtigungenType"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="mitnahmenachweiseType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="mitnahmenachweis" type="tns:mitnahmenachweisType"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="auftraggeberType1">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="firmenIDAuftraggeber" type="xsd:positiveInteger"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="auftraggeberType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="firmenIDAuftraggeber" type="xsd:positiveInteger"/>
                <xsd:element name="auftraggeberName">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="qS" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="gegenstaendeType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="gegenstand">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:simpleType name="farbeEnum">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="gruen"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="blau"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="rot"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="gelb"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:complexType name="fahrzeugtypenType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="fahrzeugtyp">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:simpleType name="zusatzberechtigungEnum">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="M"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="S"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Y"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Z"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="L"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="B"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="C"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="F"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="R"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:complexType name="klassenType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="klasse">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>

        <xsd:element name="uebermittleAusweisdatenRequest">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="ausweis" type="tns:ausweisType1"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="uebermittleAusweisdatenResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="ausweis" type="tns:ausweisType"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="fahrgenehmigung" type="tns:fahrgenehmigungType"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="mitarbeiter" type="tns:mitarbeiterType"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="berechtigung" type="tns:berechtigungType"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="fahrerlaubnis" type="tns:fahrerlaubnisType"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="lieferant" type="tns:lieferantType"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="uebermittleAusweisdatenRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="in" element="tns:uebermittleAusweisdatenRequest"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="uebermittleAusweisdatenResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="out" element="tns:uebermittleAusweisdatenResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ZKS-EAPPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="uebermittleAusweisdaten">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:uebermittleAusweisdatenRequest" wsa:Action="http://security.fraport.de/zks-eap/uebermittleAusweisdatenRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:uebermittleAusweisdatenResponse" wsa:Action="http://security.fraport.de/zks-eap/uebermittleAusweisdatenResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="ZKS-EAPSOAP" type="tns:ZKS-EAPPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsaw:UsingAdressing wsaw:required="true"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="uebermittleAusweisdaten">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://security.fraport.de/zks-eap/uebermittleAusweisdaten"/>
      <wsdl:input name="uebermittleAusweisdatenRequest">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ZKSEAPService">
    <wsdl:port name="ZKSEAPPort" binding="tns:ZKS-EAPSOAP">
      <soap:address location="http://services.fraport.de/ANY/ANY"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

And Here is my full stacktrace:

[image: error]

Is there something wrong with my WSDL? Thanks.

EDIT: XML Configuration Schema Added

Here is my configuration on mule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns:wmq="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq/current/mule-wmq-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">
    <custom-transformer name="StringToNameString" class="de.fraport.sources.StringtoAusweis" doc:name="Java"/>
    <data-mapper:config name="json_to_xml" transformationGraphPath="json_to_xml.grf" doc:name="json_to_xml"/>
    <wmq:connector name="WMQ" hostName="localhost" port="1414" queueManager="localmanager"  validateConnections="true" doc:name="WMQ"  />

    <flow name="RequestFlow" doc:name="RequestFlow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="uebermittleAusweisdaten" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <expression-filter expression="#[message.payload !='/favicon.ico']" doc:name="Expression"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="json_to_xml" doc:name="JSON To XML"/>
        <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="D:\Workspace\soaptest\mobako.sender.xsl" doc:name="XSLT"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-service doc:name="SOAP Service" soapVersion="1.2" serviceClass="de.fraport.security.ZKSEAPService"/>
        <wmq:outbound-endpoint queue="LSMH.ZKS.SERVICEBUS" connector-ref="WMQ" doc:name="ZKSEAP IN"/>
    </flow>

</mule>
```

Comment: No your WSDL is alright, NamespaceURI: http://security.fraport.de/zks-eap is also okay. please check at SOAP Bindings. seems Issue over there

Comment: @subhkriti I have edited my question and add my configuration on mule. I have tried to find something wrong on that configuration too, but for now, I can not find anything. Thanks

Comment: For the sake of testing , could you please change your soapVersion="1.2" to 1.1 and check. Not very sure but it's not been supported by all toolkits. Thanks

Comment: <inbound-endpoint address="http://${Host_Name}:${PORT}/ServiceName" exchange-pattern="request-response" />

Comment: @subhkriti, I have change the inbound-endpoint into this <inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/ZKSEAPService" exchange-pattern="request-response" />, but I still got the same error. And for the soapVersion, if I change it into 1.1 then I will get another error.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I was receiving the same error and In my application it was related to the Java classes not part of the same package.

Comment: Was a solution found for this issue? I'm facing exactly similar issue and trying to find the root cause. And I wonder why the error message is showing a POJO class name here ("uebermittleAusweisdatenRequest" in this case). This is message is supposed to have an operation name instead. Same is happening in my case too.